# DXR: How to identify the geometry instance of the bottom level AS inside the closest hit shader

Tags: hlsl, raytracing, directx-12

I have multiple geometries (D3D12_RAYTRACING_GEOMETRY_DESC) inside of a single DXR bottom level acceleration structure (BLAS). How can I determine which of those was hit inside of a closest hit shader?
The following HLSL intrinsics do something different:

- PrimitiveIndex() returns the triangle index for the current geometry, but it restarts for each new geometry inside of the BLAS, so I don't know which one was hit.
- InstanceIndex() returns the index of the top level but not of the bottom level
- InstanceID() again, is only defined for the top level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with `D3D12_RAYTRACING_TIER_1_1` there is a new intrinsic called `uint GeometryIndex()` [Specification](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Specs/blob/master/d3d/Raytracing.md#geometryindex).

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering about that as well. Unfortunately, I can't give you a definitive answer but on [this page](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/effectively-integrating-rtx-ray-tracing-real-time-rendering-engine/) I found the following statement:

> Since hit groups need information about the geometry that was hit –
>   its vertex data and material properties – you typically need a local
>   root table for them. To avoid passing data through the local root
>   table, you may also use the instance id field in the top-level
>   instance descriptor and utilize the instance index, which are
>   implicitly available in the hit group shaders. Remember, though, that
>   these values are shared between all geometries in the instance when
>   the bottom level structure contains more than one geometry. To have
>   unique data for each geometry, a local root table must be used.

So if I understood that correctly, you either have to use a local root table or you have to restrict yourself to only one geometry per bottom level structure.

There is a MultiplierForGeometryContributionToShaderIndex parameter in TraceRay which you can set to 1 to get a different hit group per geometry. If you store a list of materials per hit group, you probably need only one hit group per geometry.

See also [RaytracingMiniEngineSample](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Raytracing).